# Login form operational

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a login form but i don't know how to make it functional. I want it to let only people i got in a list to login the others can't login. Like in a company only the employees of that company can login. Also when the person logs in  i want to make to go PF1.1.html and to save the username to display in the right bottom corner of that html page so it is possible to know whose session is initated Don't know if i'm making it clear enough but provide some feedback so i try to explain better.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    var state = false;

    //$("input:text:visible:first").focus();

    $('#accesspanel').on('submit', function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        state = !state;

        if (state) {
            document.getElementById("litheader").className = "poweron";
            document.getElementById("go").className = "";
            document.getElementById("go").value = "Initializing...";
        }else{
            document.getElementById("litheader").className = "";
            document.getElementById("go").className = "denied";
            document.getElementById("go").value = "Access Denied";
        }

    });

});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Audiowide);

::-moz-selection {
    background: #cc0000;
    text-shadow: none;
}

::selection {
    background: #cc0000;
    text-shadow: none;
}

html,body,div,span,applet,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,a,abbr,acronym,address,big,cite,code,del,dfn,em,img,ins,kbd,q,s,samp,small,strike,strong,sub,sup,tt,var,b,u,i,center,dl,dt,dd,ol,ul,li,fieldset,form,label,legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td,article,aside,canvas,details,embed,figure,figcaption,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,output,ruby,section,summary,time,mark,audio,video {
  border: 0;
  font: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section {
  display: block;
}

html,body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1;
}

.background-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  overflow: hidden;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: default;
  outline: none;
}

form {
  background: #111;
  border: 1px solid #191919;
  border-radius: .4em;
  bottom: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  height: 1000px;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 1500px;
}

form:after {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #111111, #444444, #b6b6b8, #444444, #2F2F2F, #272727);
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 1px;
  left: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 150px;
}

form:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px 4px #fff;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 5px;
  left: 34%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  width: 8px;
}

.inset {
  border-top: 1px solid #19191a;
  padding: 20px;
}

form h1 {
  font-family: 'Audiowide';
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  font-size: 200px;
  padding: 15px 0;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000;
}

form h1 {
  color: #FFbb00;
  font-family: Audiowide;
  font-weight: normal;
}

form h1.poweron {
  color: #ffffff;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  animation: flicker 1s ease-in-out 1 alternate, neon 1.5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  animation-delay: 0s, 1s;
}

form h1:after {
  position: absolute;
  width: 250px;
  height: 180px;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  pointer-events: none;
  top: 0;
  margin-left: 138px;
  transform-style: flat;
  transform: skew(20deg);

  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, hsla(0,0%,100%,0.1) 0%, hsla(0,0%,100%,0) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,hsla(0,0%,100%,0.2)), color-stop(100%,hsla(0,0%,100%,0)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, hsla(0,0%,100%,0.1) 0%,hsla(0,0%,100%,0) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, hsla(0,0%,100%,0.1) 0%,hsla(0,0%,100%,0) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, hsla(0,0%,100%,0.1) 0%,hsla(0,0%,100%,0) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#42ffffff', endColorstr='#00ffffff',GradientType=0 );
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, hsla(0,0%,100%,0.1) 0%,hsla(0,0%,100%,0) 100%);

}

input[type=text], input[type=password] {
  background: linear-gradient(#1f2124,#27292c);
  border: 1px solid #222;
  border-radius: .3em;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

input[type=text]:disabled, input[type=password]:disabled {
 color: #999;
}

label[for=remember] {
  color: #bbb;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 0 0 0 5px;
}

.p-container {
  padding: 0 20px 20px;
}

.p-container:after {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.p-container span {
  color: #0d93ff;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding-top: 8px;
}

input[type=submit] {
  background: #fb0;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  border-radius: .3em;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.3), inset 0 10px 10px rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
  color: #873C00;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 100px;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  width: 100%;
}

.denied {
  color: white !important;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px black;
  background: #EE0000 !important;
}

input[type=submit]:hover, input[type=submit]:focus {
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.3), inset 0 -10px 10px rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
}

input[type=text]:hover:not([disabled]), 
input[type=text]:focus, 
input[type=password]:hover:not([disabled]), 
input[type=password]:focus, 
label:hover ~ input[type=text], 
label:hover ~ input[type=password] {
  background: #27292c;
}


@keyframes neon {
  from {
    text-shadow: 
    0 0 2.5px #fff,
    0 0 5px #fff,
    0 0 7.5px #fff,
    0 0 10px #B6FF00,
    0 0 17.5px #B6FF00,
    0 0 20px #B6FF00,
    0 0 25px #B6FF00,
    0 0 37.5px #B6FF00;
  }

  to {
      text-shadow: 
      0 0 3px #fff,
      0 0 7px  #fff,
      0 0 13px  #fff,
      0 0 17px  #B6FF00,
      0 0 33px  #B6FF00,
      0 0 38px  #B6FF00,
      0 0 48px #B6FF00,
      0 0 63px #B6FF00;
    }
}

@keyframes flicker {
  0% {
    text-shadow: 
    0 0 2.5px #fff,
    0 0 5px #fff,
    0 0 7.5px #fff,
    0 0 10px #B6FF00,
    0 0 17.5px #B6FF00,
    0 0 20px #B6FF00,
    0 0 25px #B6FF00,
    0 0 37.5px #B6FF00;
  }

  2% {
    text-shadow: none;
  }

  8% {
    text-shadow: 
    0 0 2.5px #fff,
    0 0 5px #fff,
    0 0 7.5px #fff,
    0 0 10px #B6FF00,
    0 0 17.5px #B6FF00,
    0 0 20px #B6FF00,
    0 0 25px #B6FF00,
    0 0 37.5px #B6FF00;
  }

  10% {
    text-shadow: none;
  }

  20% {
    text-shadow: 
    0 0 2.5px #fff,
    0 0 5px #fff,
    0 0 7.5px #fff,
    0 0 10px #B6FF00,
    0 0 17.5px #B6FF00,
    0 0 20px #B6FF00,
    0 0 25px #B6FF00,
    0 0 37.5px #B6FF00;
  }

  22% {
    text-shadow: none;
  }

  24% {
    text-shadow: 
    0 0 2.5px #fff,
    0 0 5px #fff,
    0 0 7.5px #fff,
    0 0 10px #B6FF00,
    0 0 17.5px #B6FF00,
    0 0 20px #B6FF00,
    0 0 25px #B6FF00,
    0 0 37.5px #B6FF00;
  }

  28% {
    text-shadow: none;
  }

  32% {
    text-shadow: 
    0 0 2.5px #fff,
    0 0 5px #fff,
    0 0 7.5px #fff,
    0 0 10px #B6FF00,
    0 0 17.5px #B6FF00,
    0 0 20px #B6FF00,
    0 0 25px #B6FF00,
    0 0 37.5px #B6FF00;
  }

  34% {
    text-shadow: none;
  }

  36% {
    text-shadow: none;
  }

  42% {
    text-shadow: none;
  }

  100% {
    text-shadow: 
    0 0 2.5px #fff,
    0 0 5px #fff,
    0 0 7.5px #fff,
    0 0 10px #B6FF00,
    0 0 17.5px #B6FF00,
    0 0 20px #B6FF00,
    0 0 25px #B6FF00,
    0 0 37.5px #B6FF00;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Desk+ - Grupo 36</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="PF1.css">
<script src="PF1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="Locked Screen">
    <div id="Login">
            <div class="background-wrap">
                    <div class="background"></div>
                  </div>
                  
                  <form id="accesspanel" action="login" method="post">
                    <h1 id="litheader">Desk+</h1>
                    <div class="inset">
                      <p>
                        <input type="text" name="username" id="email" placeholder="Username">
                      </p>
                      <p>
                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
                      </p>
                      <div style="text-align: center;">
                      <input class="loginLoginValue" type="hidden" name="service" value="login" />
                    </div>
                    <p class="p-container">
                      <input type="submit" name="Login" id="go" value="Login">
                    </p>
                  </form>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And when the person can't login i want it to do the same as this one does: https://codepen.io/aecend/pen/JoLzqr

Comment: you can use php for that

Comment: How do i do it then?

Comment: only employee can login ? for that you need to set database

Comment: Logging in only makes sense when a backend is involved. Judging from your question you don't have one. I'd do some basic tutorials PHP first, to learn about server-side code, and sessions. Otherwise you're aren't creating a login system, just something that pretends to be one.

Comment: So if i create a php doc i can make a functional login?

Comment: @ChrisG i don't know if i'm asking too much but can u please make it for this login so it is functional?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I'd love to help, but the internet is full of tutorials. Install xampp, pick a PHP tutorial, and go! Good luck!

Comment: I made loads of php pages with it already but i can't open them in my browser

Comment: You'd have to be more specific about the circumstances and the issue than that. It might be better to open a new question about your PHP problems directly. Fix that first, and then return to this project

Answer (score 0):

## PHP login app

I attempted to answer this question using PHP for the back end processing.

I did not try and write it myself. I searched for a simple script to serve as a sample.

credit: thedevdojo

https://github.com/thedevdojo/php-login-script

This is based on a PHP solution for the back end, but I modified to use Ajax and to use your style sheet and cosmetic javascript.

This only serves as an example and may have some serious security holes.  If your app is internet facing, as opposed to being on a private network, then I would consider researching more regarding front end security.

Here is a simple flow of the process.

[image: flow of login].

### register.php

I included the register feature because it uses the php password_hash to encrypt the password.  I don't know much about how secure this is, but it does encrypt the password so that the password is not stored in the database in clear form.
this script does not send emails,but uses the email address as the username.

https://php.net/manual/de/function.password-hash.php

```html
<?php

session_start();

if( isset($_SESSION['user_id']) ){
    header("Location: /");
}

require 'database.php';

$message = '';

if(!empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['password'])):
    
    // Enter the new user in the database
    $sql = "INSERT INTO myAppUsers (email, password) VALUES (:email, :password)";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':password', password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT));

    if( $stmt->execute() ):
        $message = 'Successfully created new user';
    else:
        $message = 'Sorry there must have been an issue creating your account';
    endif;

endif;

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Register Below</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="header">
        <a href="/">Your App Name</a>
    </div>

    <?php if(!empty($message)): ?>
        <p><?= $message ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <h1>Register</h1>
    <span>or <a href="login.php">login here</a></span>

    <form action="register.php" method="POST">
        
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your email" name="email">
        <input type="password" placeholder="and password" name="password">
        <input type="password" placeholder="confirm password" name="confirm_password">
        <input type="submit">

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

### database.php

You will notice that the other pages require the database.php This is where you put your database login info.

```php
<?php

     $dbHost     = "localhost";
     $dbUsername = "yourdbusername";
     $dbPassword = "yourdbpassword";
     $dbName     = "yourdbname";


try{
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbHost;dbname=$dbName;", $dbUsername, $dbPassword);
} catch(PDOException $e){
    die( "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage());
}
```

### checklogin.php

This is the php code that does the database lookup which is called via ajax from the javascript. Again, probably security holes but it works.

This uses the php password_verify function to see if the encrypted password is matching.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

```php
<?php
require 'database.php';

if(!empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['password'])):
    
    $records = $conn->prepare('SELECT id,email,password FROM myAppUsers WHERE email = :email');
    $records->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email']);
    $records->execute();
    $results = $records->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $message = '';

    if(count($results) > 0 && password_verify($_POST['password'], $results['password']) ){

        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $results['id'];
        //header("Location: /tutorials/2019042902/private/");
        echo "success";

    } else {
        echo "fail";
        //$message = 'Sorry, those credentials do not match';
    }

endif;
```

### login.php

The php code at the top checkes the session to see if it is set and automatically redirects.  Not sure if you want that feature or not but it was there.  This is necessary in order for the encrypt/decrypt to work.

```html
<?php

session_start();

if( isset($_SESSION['user_id']) ){
    header("Location: /tutorials/2019042902/private/");
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login Below</title>
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css">-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/customstyle.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>


<div class="background-wrap">
  <div class="background"></div>
</div>

<form id="accesspanel" action="login.php" method="post">
  <h1 id="litheader">LOGIN</h1>
  <div class="inset">
    <p>
      <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email address">
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Access code">
    </p>
    <div style="text-align: center;">
      <div class="checkboxouter">
        <input type="checkbox" name="rememberme" id="remember" value="Remember">
        <label class="checkbox"></label>
      </div>
      <label for="remember">Remember me for 14 days</label>
    </div>
    <input class="loginLoginValue" type="hidden" name="service" value="login" />
  </div>
  <p class="p-container">
    <input type="submit" name="Login" id="go" value="Authorize">
  </p>
</form>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/script.js?version=20190430v01"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

### assets/js/script.js

The javascript with the ajax that calls checklogin.php

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    var state = false;

    //$("input:text:visible:first").focus();

    $('#accesspanel').on('submit', function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        document.getElementById("litheader").className = "poweron";
        document.getElementById("go").className = "";
        document.getElementById("go").value = "Initializing...";

        $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: 'checklogin.php',
               data: $(this).serialize(),
               success: function(data)
               {
                  if (data === 'success') {
                    window.location = 'private/index.php';
                  }
                  else {
                    //alert('Invalid Credentials');
                    document.getElementById("litheader").className = "";
                    document.getElementById("go").className = "denied";
                    document.getElementById("go").value = "Access Denied";
                    //alert(data);    
                  }
               }
        });




        /*
        state = !state;

        if (state) {
            document.getElementById("litheader").className = "poweron";
            document.getElementById("go").className = "";
            document.getElementById("go").value = "Initializing...";
        }else{
            document.getElementById("litheader").className = "";
            document.getElementById("go").className = "denied";
            document.getElementById("go").value = "Access Denied";
        }
        */

    });

});
```

### logout.php

If you want the users to be able to logout.  I noticed that your dialog has the remember me for 14 days feature.  I did not implement that.

```php
<?php

session_start();

session_unset();

session_destroy();

header("Location: /");
```